# Retrieve checkbox options after submit

Tags: php

I am building this function which echo-s all table fields and has a checkbox along with it.

I need to print this fields after submission, i have this code, and no i haven't started something, not because i don't want but because i don't have any idea how to.. so i'm asking your help.

I need to print information in report.php please help.

```
<form action='report.php' method='post'>

<?php // Script 12.7 - sopping.php

$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('db_up', $db);

echo "<table border='1' class='tabtext'>";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hostess");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$numfields = mysql_num_fields($result);

// show headers
echo '<thead><tr>';
for ($field = 0; $field < $numfields; $field++) {
    $field_name = mysql_field_name($result, $field); // instead of $i
    echo '<th><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[' . $field_name . '][]" value="1"/> ' . $field_name . '</label></th>';
}

echo '</tr></thead>';

echo '<tbody>';
for ($row = 0; $row < $numrows; $row++) {
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($field = 0; $field < $numfields; $field++) {
        $field_name = mysql_field_name($result, $field);
        if (isset($_POST['checkbox'][$field_name])) {
            echo '<td>' . $data[$field_name] . '</td>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';


?>
<input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

The report.php

```
<?php // Script 12.7 - sopping.php

$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('db_up', $db);

foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $key => $value)

?>
```

Comment: tried foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $key => $value) after submit?

Comment: Can you please tell me how am i supposed to print that? sorry, i'm just a beginner...

Comment: can you copy and paste the output HTML of the above?

Comment: it won't show me anything, that's why i asked.. see my updated code please

Comment: I think the way you setting the checkbox name is not right - perhaps name="checkbox[' . $field_name . '] should be name="checkbox[' . $field_name . '][]

Comment: ah well, it seems more difficult now, so what am i suppose to do?
Please be aware that i'm a beginner, i'm not asking you to code for me :)
if you can give me the logic...

Comment: well try the above and see if it works/output something?

Comment: i have updated the code as per above and still nothing, can you check if i have inserted the form submission code correct? maybe i haven't put the <form> </form> as i should.. i don' know.. becaus ei have no errors or something...

Comment: best to backup this file and add additional items bit by bit - for example - just create <form ...> <input type="checkbox" name="chckboxname" value="some value" /> <input type="submit" value="submit" /> </form> and see if it prints ... if it works add rest of the codes step by step.

Comment: @HappyApe You are correct, the name attribute in the form should be `name="checkbox[]"` or `name="checkbox['.$field_name.']"` if you want to set keys, even though I would choose another name for the array. by doing `name="checkbox[' . $field_name . '][]"`, you are creating a multidemsional array. By setting keys you can do `$_POST['checkbox[\'User_name\']']`

Comment: Thanks guys :)
I'll do as you suggested!
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    echo "<pre>";
    $checked = implode(',', $_POST['checkbox']);
    echo $checked;
}
```